# How to reduce following expression

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have following expression which I'm using in programming, but when value of $N$ and $M$ is very high it's taking long time to give result. Is there any way I can reduce this expression, so that I've to do less number of computations. 
$$P = \sum_{i=1}^{R - 1} {N \choose i} \cdot {M \choose {R - i}} \cdot i \cdot (R - i).$$

Comment: Note $k{n\choose k}=n{n-1\choose k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that (see Gerry Myerson's comment), for $1\leq i\geq R-1$,
$$\binom{N}{i}=\frac{N}{i}\binom{N-1}{i-1},\quad \binom{M}{R - i}
=\frac{M}{R-i}\binom{M-1}{R - i-1}.$$
Therefore
\begin{align} 
\sum_{i=1}^{R - 1} \binom{N}{i} \binom{M}{R - i}  i  (R - i)&=
 NM\sum_{i=1}^{R-1} \binom{N-1}{i-1} \binom{M-1}{R -i-1}\\ &=NM\sum_{k=0}^{R-2} \binom{N-1}{k} \binom{M-1}{(R -2) -k}\\
&=NM\binom{N+M-2}{R-2}
\end{align}
where in the last step we used the [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).